# Heroku - Custom 404 Page using ERROR_PAGE_URL not working

Tags: heroku, server, http-status-code-404, heroku-cli

For my website, I am trying to create a custom 404 Error page.

Using the following command in the Heroku CLI:

```
heroku config:set \ 
ERROR_PAGE_URL=//MyWebsiteName.com/public/404.html
```

The error page gets successfully set. However, when I load a page that my website does not have, eg, www.MyWebsiteName.com/3213123, the browser does not load my 404.html customised error message. Instead, it just gives a generic 404 response:

[404 error, not my custom 404 page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ar42v.png)

Can anyone please explain what I am doing wrong?
I was following this link as a reference:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-pages#customize-pages

Thank you,

Comment: "the browser does not load my 404.html customised error message"—what does it do instead?

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for the reply, I will include the screenshot of what it does instead

Comment: Are you sure you configured the correct Heroku application? Does `http://MyWebsiteName.com/public/404.html` load properly in a browser?

Comment: Yes, the page really exists on my website. I am going to try saving my custom 404 page on AWS S3 and see if that works.

Comment: I still have not got a solution to this problem. If anyone knows please let me know!

Answer (score 1):

For a php app on Heroku, the error page can be set by creating an .htaccess file in your root directory (or adding the line below to the file if you've already created it) and setting the 404 there.

**.htaccess**

```
ErrorDocument 404 /my-404-page.php
```

Push to Heroku and that is all you need (assuming, of course, that you have also created a "my-404-page.php").

Setting this error page via the settings > configuration variables also did not work for me. For me, this worked.

Answer (score 1):

Only Heroku level errors will use the ERROR_PAGE_URL. 404 error pages is an application responsibility.

From https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-pages :

> Other errors, such as application errors (a 404 or 500), will display your application’s error page and not the Heroku error page. Only system-level errors that result in no response, or a malformed one, will display the Heroku error page discussed here.

Answer (score 1):

Since no answer was accepted, here's my **Answer**:

What you described is a missing route.

Missing routes are your application's responsibility. It can be fixed in your own code, by creating a generic route in your `server.js` or `App.js` (if you use React for example), where you serve your own 404 page.

Although a more ideal solution is to route the user somewhere meaningful, like the /landing page or the user /home page.